# log4j.Logger is not compatible with logging.Logger with JDK 1.8

Tags: java, logging, java-8, log4j

My project is compiled with JDK 1.5. I use an interface `java.sql.Driver` which implements a method `getParentLogger`:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
...
public interface Driver {
  ...
  public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;
}
```

My class `MockDriver` implements this interface :

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
...
class MockDriver implements Driver {
...
   public Logger getParentLogger() {
       return LOGGER;
   }
}
```

Like that, it works for me when i compile.

But when using JDK 1.8 in my project, i have an error :

```
error: MockDriver is not abstract and does not override abstract method 
getParentLogger() in Driver
error: getParentLogger() in MockDriver cannot implement getParentLogger() in 
Driver
return type org.apache.log4j.Logger is not compatible with 
java.util.logging.Logger
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: use the other logger

Comment: @Stultuske But like that it works with JDK 1.5 ! I don't want to change it for this moment.

Comment: Apparently java.sql.Driver interface has been changed between 1.5 and 1.8 java versions. Is there any reason, why you don't use frameworks like Mockito for mocking objects?

Comment: @Michal I started working with this project for 2 days so realy i don't know. Maybe it already exists and the development team is working with.

Comment: @youssef so don't upgrade to Java 1.8